# Highlight all comma's in page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a very very simple question and i didn't find my answer.

I have a page that is using ajax and it gets update again and again in one div of it.

Now, i want to Highlight ALL the commas `,` of that **div**.
For example, they get red color.

How can i do it with this *ajax* page ?

I also wanted to try with *this* code, but i coudn't

```
$(document":contains(',')").css("color","red");
```

I just need to find all the commas in that div every second and give a style to them .

How to do it with jquery?

Comment: You can't style individual characters in a single element. If you want to style only commas then you need to parse the AJAX responses and wrap the commas in span elements that you change the color of.

Comment: I would replace the commas before inserting them into the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about jQuery, but it can be done with pure javascript. But it's not so easy actually.

#### [tl;dr jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/nztxhjc9/)

**This answer does not cause DOM revalidation and does not mess-up with javascript events!**

First you need to loop through page content and replace every comma (or every character) with a `<span>` or other node so that you can give it individual CSS style. Let's start with getting textNodes:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getTextNodes = function(recursive, uselist) {
  var list = this.childNodes;
  var nodes = uselist!=null?uselist:[];
  for(var i=0,l=list.length; i<l;i++) {
    if(list[i].nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      nodes.push(list[i]);
    }
    else if(recursive==true&&list[i].nodeType==1&&list[i].tagName.toLowerCase()!="script"&&list[i].tagName.toLowerCase()!="style") {
      list[i].getTextNodes(true, nodes);
    }
  }
  //console.log(nodes);
  return nodes;
}
```

You'll now need to split the spans wherever the commas are:

```
/*Turn single text node into many spans containing single letters */
  /* @param
       textNode - HTMLTextNode element
       highlight - the character to highlight
     @return
       null
  */
  function replaceLetters(textNode, highlight) {
    //Get the string contained in the text node
    var text = textNode.data;
    //Generate a container to contain text-node data
    var container = document.createElement("span");
    //Create another span for every single letter
    var tinyNodes = [];
    //Split the letters in spans
    for(var i=0,l=text.length;i<l; i++) {
      //skip whitespace
      if(text[i].match(/^\s*$/)) {
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text[i]));
      }
      //Create a span with the letter
      else {
        //Create a span
        var tiny = document.createElement("span");
        //If the letter is our character
        if(text[i]==highlight) 
          tiny.className = "highlighted";
        tiny.innerHTML = text[i];
        container.appendChild(tiny);
      }
    }
    //replace text node with a span
    textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(container, textNode);
    textNode.parentNode.removeChild(textNode);
  }
```

The function above was originaly used for animating all letters on a page (even when it was already loaded). You only need to change color of some of these.

If the functions above are defined, call this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("myDiv").getTextNodes(true);
for(var i=0, l=nodes.length; i<l; i++) {
    replaceLetters(nodes[i], ",");
}
```

Comment: Very nice approach! You can see the event preserved here: http://jsfiddle.net/nztxhjc9/1/ . Using the insertBefore on the text node was very smart.

Comment: @TravisJ I have created a [better version](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/nztxhjc9/3/) allowing to search multi-character strings. It also creates less nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the commas with an HTML tag (such as `<span>`).

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.target').each(function() {
        var string = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(string.replace(/,/g , '<span class="comma">,</span>'));
    });
});
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mh6ja1L/

Comment: This will only work if there are no events beneath `.target`.

Comment: @TravisJ See my answer if you prefer somtehing that uses native DOM functions instead of string replacing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in jQuery but in pure JavaScript it would be something like this:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("content");
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, "<b class='highlight'>,</b>");
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/f9xs0c79/

Comment: What if there is `<img src="..." alt="Me, baking a baby" />`?

Comment: True, but it's only a basic example. If OP have div with only text this is good aproach.

Answer (score -1):

No need to do loop. You can just select the container where you want to replace and replace.

```
$("p").html(
    $("p").html().replace(/,/g,"<span class='comma'>,</span>")
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1570ya75/2/

Comment: Replacing is loop as well. It's just loop you don't see. It also causes DOM re-validation as far as I know.

Comment: See others suggestion, like Aziz, they are looping + doing replace. Here, I do not loop.

Comment: Yes, you just take HTML, change it as a string and then let the browsers validate it once again. `jQuery` is doing the loops on background. But they still happen.

Comment: Sorry, but this is completely wrong. This will take the content from the *first* `p` element, and set it as the content of *all* the `p` elements. And not only that, but it only actually replaces the first `,` character found.

Comment: I updated the solution. You were right @cookiemonster

Comment: But you didn't fix the worst part of it. Re-read the first part of my comment.